# What type of non-linear model would I use to predict a continuous outcome based on continuous variable and several factors (in R)?

Tags: generalized-additive-model

Title pretty much sums it up.  I can use a generalized additive model to predict a continuous outcome from continuous variables, but it is my understanding that factor variables are not well suited for GAM's. What types of models would allow me to incorporate factors as well? (and what are my best options to implement these models using R?)

Comment: "It is my understanding that factor variables are not well suited for GAM's" - do you have a source for this? I don't see anything inherently wrong with this. Just bumps up or down a smoothed continuous curve depending on whether or not the factor is a problem. Alternately, you do stratification if the curves are not sufficiently parallel.

Comment: @AdamO Do you mean something like "whether or not the factor is present" in your comment?

Comment: @Glen_b You're right it's unclear. What I meant was "...depending on whether or not the factor is actually additive in the model." implying one could use a more flexible method and fit interactions.